# Retrieving Eclipse console history

Tags: eclipse

Is there any way I can retrieve the `Ecipse` console log history? Whenever I run the program, does `Eclipse` create a log file and store somewhere? I have seen that we can manually create an outuput file, but what if I have not created one yet? Does `Eclipse` store somewhere by default?

Answer (score 13):

No, Eclipse doesn't store it by default. There are two options to enable this:

The first method is to tell Eclipse to save console output to a file. For that, go to Run -> Debug Configurations on Eclipse menu. Then under "Standard Input and Output" section, click on checkbox next to "File:", and choose the name of output file to use. If you check "Append" underneath, console output will be appended to the output file. Otherwise, console output will be overwritten to the file.

The other way is to use explicit file logging from your application and store it anywhere you want.

Comment: In my version of Eclipse Neon 4.6.3, under Debug Configurations, the Standard Input/Ouput section is  under the "Common" tab on the right hand pane.